# python manage.py runserver not connecting

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, cookiecutter-django

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Is not running and this is this traceback I'm receiving:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\David\Envs\ebdjango\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\David\Envs\ebdjango\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 123, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "C:\Users\David\Envs\ebdjango\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 427, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "C:\Users\David\Envs\ebdjango\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\David\Envs\ebdjango\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "C:\Users\David\Envs\ebdjango\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 207, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "C:\Users\David\Envs\ebdjango\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 61, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "C:\Users\David\Envs\ebdjango\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 44, in has_table
    return self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor())
  File "C:\Users\David\Envs\ebdjango\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 255, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "C:\Users\David\Envs\ebdjango\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 232, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "C:\Users\David\Envs\ebdjango\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\David\Envs\ebdjango\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\David\Envs\ebdjango\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\David\Envs\ebdjango\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 194, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\David\Envs\ebdjango\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 168, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\David\Envs\ebdjango\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 130, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?`

I can not see why the server is not connecting? I am using [django-cookiecutter](https://cookiecutter-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) I'm not sure if I should change the port being used or it is something else?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: There is a lot that is involved in CookieCutter. The 5432 port issue looks like it is trying to connect to a PostgreSQL database/server. Do you have that configured in your env variables or settings file?

Comment: I actually just realised my postgres db is not configured corectly. that was the problem! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My postgresql software was not installed correctly Thanks @dfundako!